# Access local storage from content script in Chrome extension programing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to develop a Chrome extension. In it I have one option page and a `contentscript.js` both registered in `manifest.js`.

I have used local storage in `option.js`. Now I want to access data of local storage from `contentscript.js` so I found following code to send request to `background.js` from `contentscript.js`:

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({method: "getStatus"}, function(response) {
  console.log(response.status);
});
```

And `background.js` using following to respond:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
if (request.method == "getStatus")
       sendResponse({status: localStorage['status']});
else
       sendResponse({}); });
```

Now it is showing following error:

> undefined in line "console.log(response.status);" in file contentscript.js .

What is the problem with that?
How can I get whole local storage access from `contentscript.js`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like working code.
Check your manifest file and localStorage.status

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html

Comment: Why localStorage.status is returning **undefined** ?? When i m passing   localStorage.length it is showing right length. Now my next ques was that how can i pass **whole local storage** to **contentscript** as a response ??

Comment: Use JSON.stringify() with localStorage. Send this string to contentscript and use JSON.parse() to get object